# How can I update a table by using subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, self-reference

I have got table which is  "Stocks". There are thousands of records inside of this table and I need to UPDATE it acc. to following Example. (I use SQL Server 2008)

```
STOCKS.stock_name     STOCKS.a_id
A.001                  0
B.001                  0
C.001                 20
A.002                  0
B.002                 10
A.003                  0
```

After executing the code, I want to have a table which is like:

```
STOCKS.stock_name     STOCKS.a_id
A.001                 20
B.001                 20
C.001                 20
A.002                 10
B.002                 10
A.003                  0
```

What needs to happen here is that the SQL understands 001 - 002 and 003 are 3 different groups. (I'm thinking about using SUBSTRING(stock_name,3,20) since the first 2 part of my text value will not be like "**AA.002**". Grouping will start from the third part of each stock name.) It selects the maximum **a.id** value and update the rows accordingly. I really need your help about this issue.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Hello Gordon, Many thanks for your comment. I've edited my question thansk to you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possibility.  I used table variables for clarity.  You may want to stick some of this into sub-queries.  But this should work right away.

```
-- Your example data for demonstration purposes.
CREATE TABLE #STOCKS (stock_name nvarchar(5), a_id int)
INSERT INTO #STOCKS (stock_name, a_id) VALUES ('A.001', 0)
INSERT INTO #STOCKS (stock_name, a_id) VALUES ('B.001', 0)
INSERT INTO #STOCKS (stock_name, a_id) VALUES ('C.001', 20)
INSERT INTO #STOCKS (stock_name, a_id) VALUES ('A.002', 0)
INSERT INTO #STOCKS (stock_name, a_id) VALUES ('B.002', 10)
INSERT INTO #STOCKS (stock_name, a_id) VALUES ('A.003', 0)

-- To capture the stock name fragments, and the maximum value for each name fragment.
DECLARE @StockValues TABLE (stock nvarchar(5), stockNameFrag nvarchar(5), stockValue int)
DECLARE @StockMaxValues TABLE (stockNameFrag nvarchar(5), stockMaxValue int)

-- Data captured in this variable gets used in the next subquery.
INSERT INTO @StockValues (stock, stockNameFrag, stockValue)
SELECT  s.stock_name, SUBSTRING(s.stock_name, 3, 20), s.a_id
FROM    #STOCKS s
ORDER BY s.a_id DESC

-- Now extract the maximum value for each name fragment in @StockValues.
INSERT INTO @StockMaxValues
SELECT  sv1.stockNameFrag, MAX(sv2.MaxValue)
FROM    @StockValues sv1
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT stockNameFrag, MAX(stockValue) AS MaxValue
            FROM    @StockValues
            GROUP BY stockNameFrag
            ) sv2 ON sv1.stockNameFrag = sv2.stockNameFrag AND sv1.stockValue = sv2.MaxValue
GROUP BY sv1.stock, sv1.stockNameFrag

-- Store results you want
DECLARE @Stock TABLE (stock nvarchar(5), stockMaxValue int)
INSERT INTO @Stock (stock, stockMaxValue)
SELECT  s.stock_name, smv.stockMaxValue
FROM    #STOCKS s
        INNER JOIN @StockMaxValues smv ON smv.stockNameFrag = SUBSTRING(s.stock_name, 3, 20)

-- Now update the #STOCKS table with the max value for each stock.
UPDATE  s1
SET     s1.a_id = s2.stockMaxValue
FROM    #STOCKS s1
        INNER JOIN @Stock s2 ON s1.stock_name = s2.stock

SELECT * FROM #STOCKS

-- Cleanup from the demo table.
DROP TABLE #STOCKS
```

Comment: Hello Ken. Many thanks for your input. I've used your code in order to see if it works. While doing that another idea come up to my mind for which I appreciate much. Whether your code did not work or I made a mistake. First of all I was expecting to have an UPDATE at the end of your code. But there wasn't any UPDATE. I suppose you wanted me to handle the rest :) But anyway, your contribution made it possible for which I thank you very much again! I'll share the code below this.

Comment: You're welcome Baris. You're right, I didn't originally apply an update to that solution.  It's revised now so that it will update the #STOCKS table.  I added a table variable (@Stock) and the UPDATE statement. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
update stocks s
    set id = (select max(s2.id) from stocks s2 where substring(s2.stock_name, 3, 20) = substring(s.stockname, 3, 20)
               )
    where s.id = 0;
```

Comment: Hello Gordon, Many thanks for your feedback. However It didn't work. I suppose you wanted me to execute the following code (If I'm wrong please correct me):

Comment: Update Stocks
    set a.id = (select max(T1.a_id) from Stocks as T1 left outer join Stocks as T2 on T1.a_RECno = T2.a_RECno where substring(T1.a_id, 3, 20) = substring(T2.a_id, 3, 20))
where a_id = 0

Comment: The reason why I changed your code as above is that I'm not sure if I can type a code like: update t
    set a.id = (select max(a.id) from t t2  [What do you mean by "t t2"] I thought maybe you were trying to tell me that I should reference a replication table and  threfore I joined the same table as T2. But it didn't work. As I told you, all of the recored have been updated and a_id has been set as the maximum amount from the relevant column.

Answer (score 0):

This will update a `stock_name`

```
UPDATE s
SET s.a_id = (
        SELECT MAX(a_id) 
        FROM Stocks
        WHERE SUBSTRING(stock_name, 3, 20) = SUBSTRING(s.stock_name, 3, 20)
)
FROM Stocks s
WHERE SUBSTRING(s.stock_name, 3, 20) = '001'
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. However this code would only update those stock names which ends by '001'. Nevertheless, if I remove the where condition which is at the end of the code, the code would change the entire s.a_id column and set it as the max value from the table. In our case all of the values would turn into 20 since it is the maximum value.

Answer (score 0):

First of all thank you all for your answers and supports. Ken Palmer's input made this answer possible for which I appreciate him much. Here is the code which works perfectly:

```
DECLARE @MAXPRIM table (StockNameFrag nvarchar(20), StockValue int)


INSERT INTO @MAXPRIM(StockNameFrag, StockValue)
SELECT SUBSTRING(stock_name,3,20), Max(a_id)
FROM Stocks
Group By SUBSTRING(stock_name,3,20)

UPDATE STOCKS
set a_id = (select StockValue from @MAXPRIM where StockNameFrag =SUBSTRING(stock_name,3,20))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update all rows, the query below should work.

```
UPDATE s
SET s.a_id = b.max_value
FROM Stocks s
JOIN (
    SELECT SUBSTRING(stock_name, 3, 20) AS 'stock_name', MAX(a_id) 'max_value'
    FROM Stocks s
    GROUP BY  SUBSTRING(s.stock_name, 3, 20)
) b on b.stock_name = SUBSTRING(s.stock_name, 3, 20)
```