# Trying to copy or somehow move the contents (values) in a TEXT column 3k+ large rows to another table in the same database without success

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have created a new column in the "destination" table with the same name, datatype and other values as appear in the "source" column in a different table.  I have tried many suggested solutions as found on stackoverflow.  This one appeared to work (found on Quora) but when I went to the destination table the previously empty column remains empty with nothing but NULL values noted.  This is the Quora suggestion:

> you can fill data in column from another existing one by using INSERT INTO statement and SELECT statement together like that
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO `table1`(column_name)
> SELECT column_name FROM `table2`
> ```
>
> here you filled a single column in table 1 with data located in a single column in table 2
>
> so if you want to fill the whole table 1 (all columns) with data located in table 2 you can make table 1 like a copy of table 2 by using the same code but without column name
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO `table1`
> SELECT * FROM `table2`
> ```
>
> but note to do this (copy table content to another one) ensure that both of tables have the same column count and data types.

I'm not sure what is meant by column count (do the two table have to have the same number of columns?)

When I run it I get error # 1138.

Any help greatly appreciated.  -JG

Comment: If you only want to copy one column then `INSERT INTO \`table1\` (column_name)
SELECT column_name FROM \`table2\` ` should work fine.

Comment: Thanks, yes it should and apparently does.  At least that's what the output statement says.  However, when I look at table1 column name in the db there is no change to the table or column.  The column remains empty.  Nothing but NULL values.  The TEXT values just don't copy or if they do are copied to some other place.  Do you think I need to specify the exact number of rows?

Comment: More on the above.  I now see that the script given by Jerry Jeremiah works fine EXCEPT it places the transferred materials at the end of the new destination column.  That is, there are 8k rows in 5 columns in the table and I have created a empty 6th col. to receive the transferred data and it puts the transferred data in column 6, but at row 8k+1 and following.  All of the cells in the column above that are NULL.  I want the data to begin at row 1 not row 8k+1.  I wants to append the data, but I don't want it to be appended, it want it to start at the top of the table at row 1.  Thanks.  JG

Comment: Ok, so I misunderstood what you were trying to do.  `INSERT` always makes new rows.  And you are trying to add an additional column to already existing data.  So how do you match up which row in the destination table should get the column from which row in the source?  There needs to be something in the data to match them up...

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to copy/transfer all of the TEXT data in one column (18,068 cells) in the source table into the destination table (which was initially composed of six columns).  To do this, I followed a suggestion and created a blank col. in the dest. table and named it "program": A name that it shares with the col. in the source table.  

The dest. table has another column called "id" that numbers all of the rows: 1-18,068.  I'm wondering if some sort of WHERE statement that specified id=1 in the dest. table might force all of the source data into row 1 of the destination table.

Comment: So you want to update each row in the destination table with a value from the source table where the destination table's id column matches the row number of the source table?  This works http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c0c90b9/17 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/41837688/2193968 implies that http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c0c90b9/13 should work (but it doesn't and I don't know why)

Comment: Indeed, it worked!  You're a genius!  Thanks.

Comment: I figured out why it didn't work - I was testing using Oracle instead of MySQL - you would have thought I would pay more attention....  I'm glad it worked.